# How can I make the new language appear in the homepage language drop-down?

Tags: python, pylons, jinja2, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as the open data portal. I have followed all the steps in [Translating CKAN](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/i18n.html) doc except 3. Commit the translation & 5. (optional) Deploy the translation steps. But in the homepage language does not appear in the drop-down. The language I'm supposed to get is Sinhala.

How can I make the new language appear in the homepage language drop-down?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think that *Translating CKAN* page in the docs is quite out of date/just not very good. Still, if you have a `ckan/i18n/*/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.mo` file in your CKAN source directory (where `*` is the language code for your new language), and you have restarted your web server, the language should be available.

If it doesn't show up after restarting your web server, you could try setting [locale_default](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/configuration.html#config-i18n) in your config file to your new language and then restarting the web server again, and see if your language works as the default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your new language files are **on the server you are using** in the correct location and with the correct permissions - you may have to ask the administrator to do that for your and make sure you didn't miss the step of renaming to the IETF language code.

The renaming process is that you determine the [primary language code](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Language-Codes) and [country code](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Country-Codes) for example if your language is one of the many flavours of English the code is `en` this is optionally followed by a modifier lets say you are doing a British English translation rather than a general English translation you would use `en-GB` rather than `en`, (note that for English the `en` tag is most commonly used for US English).  You then use that where the example says `YOUR_LANGUAGE` N.B. The example doesn't mention using the extended country code section but that should work OK.

BTW - skipping the use of the version control system is usually a ***bad idea!***  If you are not (yet) happy to share your work just skip `git push origin translation-YOUR_LANGUAGE`.